# Two grouped products are listed on other grouped product as simple products

Tags: magento-1.9, product, grouped-products

I faced a issue that ***two specific grouped products are listed on other grouped product as simple products***

There is a grouped product called LOW t.By the way, it is shown like other items, which called LOW2, LOW3 are assigned to the simple ones of LOW. They are even grouped products tho.

It doesn't make sense as far as i know. 
Are there guys who faced this problem and fix it? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that, through an import or some other way, the grouped product was added as a child to another grouped product.

First, **back up your database**.

In your database look at the table `catalog_product_relation`. In that table look up the product that should *not* be associated to the grouped product in the `child_id` column. This will be the product ID, not the SKU. If it is in there, delete that one row.